# Using Ruby/Rails Code in Javascript File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working in an interface, that needs information from a video model I created. That means I will need to execute a MySQL query, to get information I need. My code is this, in my `interface.js.erb` file:

```
...
    function play_vid()
    {
        low_fps = '<%= @video.low_fps %>' ;
        alert(low_fps); //checking
        if(low_vid.paused){
            low_vid.play();
            play_icon.classList.remove("icon-play-circle");
            play_icon.classList.add("icon-pause");
        }else{
            low_vid.pause();
            play_icon.classList.remove("icon-pause");
            play_icon.classList.add("icon-play-circle");
        }

    }
...
```

The above code returns me this:

```
NoMethodError in Videos#show

Showing /home/user/My Projects/Ruby Projects/Video_APP/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `low_fps' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/user/My Projects/Ruby Projects/Video_APP/app/assets/javascripts/jQuery/interface.js.erb)

Extracted source (around line #8):

5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js" %> 
8:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application.js" %>
9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-dropdown.js" %>
10:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery/interface.js.erb" %>  
11:   <%= javascript_include_tag "jQuery/events_controls.js" %>
```

should I use a normal *.js file? what are the main differences and how do I fix my problem?

EDIT:

```
  # GET /videos/1
  # GET /videos/1.json
  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @video }
    end
  end
```

Comment: According to you error message, the `@video` variable is not set as `low_fps` in an undefined method. Did you check whether you actually defined `@video` in your controller?

Comment: which controller? my VideosController was generated automatically by Rails

Comment: @TestTest Whatever controller is handling the request when the `interface.js.erb` file is being rendered when it throws the error.

Comment: that controller :) as it should define the `@video` is not defined. It also might be possible that your controller was not able to find the video because it does not exist and the controller does not check this properly. If you still need more help, post (relevant parts of) the controller code (like the show method).

Comment: I dont get it. I am not using any controller to handle the interface.js.erb. I just included the file in the application.html.erb in the layout folder. I am kinda new to Rails 3 so any help will be useful. I have edited the question

Comment: You need a controller to fill in the `@video` variable which needs to be grabbed from a database depending on the video id (or something very similar). So if you indeed do not use a controller that explains your error (and @video not being defined). I would suggest to first read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ to get a better understanding of the model-view-controller(MVC) design and other Rails specific things.

Comment: I know how to render html pages using controller, I just do not know how to include javascript in them. So could anybody offer a solution to my problem?

Comment: Ruby runs on the server, and JavaScript runs in the client (the web browser).  You cannot run Ruby code from inside JavaScript code. What you *can* do is process the JavaScript file through Rails *before* you send it to the client, though that's generally not the greatest idea.

Answer (score 2):

In you view (videos/show.html.erb?) try doing following

```
<div id="video" data-lowfps="<%= @video.low_fps %>"></div>
```

and then change your JS function:

```
function play_vid()
{
    low_fps = $('#video').data('lowfps');
    alert(low_fps); //checking
    if(low_vid.paused){
        low_vid.play();
        play_icon.classList.remove("icon-play-circle");
        play_icon.classList.add("icon-pause");
    }else{
        low_vid.pause();
        play_icon.classList.remove("icon-pause");
        play_icon.classList.add("icon-play-circle");
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah I will try that later, but the thing is that I am trying to understand now how you can render, *.js using a controller like @veger said. my *.js file contains only a function, so I dont understand what there is to render. I just wanna pass a rails variable to the *.js function

Comment: To use such ruby variables you have to respond with such action - you can use <%= @video.id %> in ie. videos/show.js.erb - to (for example) overwrite some values, like number of votes. show.js.erb will be rendered after you make ajax request: $.getScript('/videos/1')

Comment: I already have a show.html.erb file, will I have to add also the show.js.erb?